# Sinon spy doesn't work

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

I have a test case like this:

```
    it("test",function(){

        var spy = sinon.spy(test,"method");
        decider = 1
        test.nextServiceTab();

        assert(spy.calledOnce);

    });
```

When the method `test.nextServiceTab` is called, it calls `method` based on the value `decider`, which is supposed to be 1. In fact the control goes to the the `method`.

But why does the control goes to the `method`? Since I'm spying it should't be right?

My goal was to just check that `method` is called. Where I'm making mistake?

Is the way I have used sinon is correct?

Comment: Can you post a simple version of your implementation of nextServiceTab()?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid control entering the function, you should use [sinon.stub](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) instead of sinon.spy. With a stub you can still see if it is called because stub implements the same interface as spy, but additionally it prevents the original function from receiving control and allows you to override the behavior.

For example, if you want the function to always return true:

```
it("test",function(){

    var stub = sinon.stub(test, "method");
    stub.returns(true);

    decider = 1;
    test.nextServiceTab();

    assert(stub.calledOnce);

    stub.restore();

});
```